# Como executar um link após a confirmação do SweetAlert?

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

Link

```
<a onClick="enviaDivida()" href="{{ route("admin.dividas.edit",$divida->id)}}"
class="btn btn-sm btn-clean btn-icon btn-icon-md" title="Enviar">
<i class="la la-send"></i> </a>
```

Script:

```
    function enviaDivida(){

    const swalWithBootstrapButtons = Swal.mixin({
    customClass: {
    confirmButton: 'btn btn-success',
    cancelButton: 'btn btn-danger'
  },
  buttonsStyling: false
})

swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire({
  title: 'Deseja realmente enviar os dados para a Central da Cobrar Simples?',
  text: "Atenção os dados serão enviados imediatamente!",
  type: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonText: 'Sim, enviar dados da dívida!',
  cancelButtonText: 'Não, cancelar!',
  reverseButtons: true
}).then((result) => {
  if (result.value) {
    swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire(
      'Cancelar!',
      'Your file has been deleted.',
      'success'
    )
  } else if (
    /* Read more about handling dismissals below */
    result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.cancel
  ) {
    swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire(
      'Processo Cancelado',
      'Nada ocorreu',
      'info'
    )
  }
})
}
```

Comment: Como assim "executar um link"?

Comment: Tipo na url tenho `href="/exluir/cliente/3"` , quando abro o `SweetAlert` quero colocar na parte onde confirma a exclusão pra poder executar o delete

Comment: Tá, mas vc quer redirecionar a página pra URL que tá no href?

Comment: Isso, na url que está dentro do href

Comment: Se vc redirecionar ao confirmar, não faz sentido abrir um outro alerta confirmando que algo aconteceu, porque a página será redirecionada e o usuário nem vai conseguir ler o alerta.

Comment: Vamos lá, quando clicar no link contendo a url `href="/exluir/cliente/3"` o Swal irá abrir, certo? Nesse momento o usuário irá decidir se cancela ou confirma a "exclusão", se confirma é redirecionado.

Comment: Na verdade o termo não é redirecionamento e sim a execução da url que após isso faz o redirecionamento pelo controller do backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `if (result.value) {` será satisfeito se o Sweetalert for confirmado. Então basta pegar o valor do `href` e redirecionar com `location.href`:

```js
function enviaDivida(e){
   e.preventDefault();

    const swalWithBootstrapButtons = Swal.mixin({
    customClass: {
    confirmButton: 'btn btn-success',
    cancelButton: 'btn btn-danger'
  },
  buttonsStyling: false
})

swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire({
  title: 'Deseja realmente enviar os dados para a Central da Cobrar Simples?',
  text: "Atenção os dados serão enviados imediatamente!",
  type: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonText: 'Sim, enviar dados da dívida!',
  cancelButtonText: 'Não, cancelar!',
  reverseButtons: true
}).then((result) => {
  if (result.value) {
    swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire(
      'Cancelar!',
      'Your file has been deleted.',
      'success'
    )
    location.href = e.target.href;
  } else if (
    /* Read more about handling dismissals below */
    result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.cancel
  ) {
    swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire(
      'Processo Cancelado',
      'Nada ocorreu',
      'info'
    )
  }
})
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/8.11.8/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>
<a onClick="enviaDivida(event)" href="./"
class="btn btn-sm btn-clean btn-icon btn-icon-md" title="Enviar">
<i class="la la-send"></i>Deletar</a>
```

Envie no `onclick` o evento como parâmetro para a função:

```
onClick="enviaDivida(event)"
```

Se quiser aplicar um click no link, basta trocar a linha `location.href = e.target.href;` por:

```
$(e.target).removeAttr("onclick");
e.target.click();
```

Comment: Aqui está apresentando no `console.log(e.target.href);` `undefined`,  está redirecionando porém o conteúdo do `href`  apresenta ``undefined``

Comment: Colocou o `event` no `onClick="enviaDivida(event)"`?

Comment: Sim, estou colocando,

Comment: No exemplo da resposta funciona direitinho.

Comment: Brother, resolvi aqui .  Passei mais um parâmetro na função pra poder pegar a url pelo     `var url = (document.getElementById(id).getAttribute("href"));` dessa forma funcionou.

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado pela disposição em ajudar. Abraços.